# CUDA Pointers, Calling Kernels

Tags: c, pointers, cuda, kernel, call

If I use pointers in a C function, like:

```
void processCalcNorm(float* a, float* b, float* c, float* d, float* e, float* f)
    {
            *a = *a + *b;
            *c = *c + *d;
            *e = *e + *f;
    }

for(id = 0; id < 1000; id++)
    {
            processCalcNorm(&xcord[id],&lvelox[id],&ycord[id],&lveloy[id],&zcord[id],&lveloz[id]);
    }
```

How should the kernel be called when it is executed?

Comment: Which kernel?  Are you suggesting you intend to create a kernel equivalent of `processCalcNorm`, or that you will call a device version of `processCalcNorm` from another kernel, or something else?

Comment: Yup I'm planning to create a kernel equivalent of processCalcNorm! But how do I call that with the variables I want?

Comment: I provided an answer because I felt it was not difficult to do so.  However, for future reference, questions like this ("write my CUDA code for me") are discouraged.  SO [expects](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "2.Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."   Next time I suggest you make an attempt yourself, and describe the issues with it.  You'll learn better that way, and it may eliminate questions about your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (written in browser, not tested):

```
__global__ void processCalcNorm_kernel(float* a, float* b, float* c, float* d, float* e, float* f, int len)
    {
       int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
       if (idx < len){
            a[idx] = a[idx] + b[idx];
            c[idx] = c[idx] + d[idx];
            e[idx] = e[idx] + f[idx];}
    }

#define DATA_LEN 1000
#define nTPB 256
...
processCalcNorm_kernel<<<(DATA_LEN+nTPB-1)/nTPB, nTPB>>>(d_xcord,d_lvelox,d_ycord,d_lveloy,d_zcord,d_lveloz,DATA_LEN);
```

Where the `d_...` variables are device copies of the similarly-named host variables, suitably set up with `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMemcpy` calls, like this (using `xcord` as an example):

```
float *d_xcord;
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_xcord, DATA_LEN*sizeof(float));
cudaMemcpy(d_xcord, xcord, DATA_LEN*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

(and create a similar sequence for the other variables)

Note that the for-loop in your original C code is no longer required, as the GPU is effectively processing each iteration of your for-loop with the single call to the kernel.

Comment: How do I print the [id] if I do not define it?

Comment: You can define an `id` variable and print it out, however you wish.  Your question is not clear to me, since your original question indicates nothing about how you want to print out data.  I suggest posting a new SO question, if you're having difficulty printing.